react-native-web expo XMLHttpRequest Error. Can't make network requests
I'm having an issue with my API requests when trying to serve by react-native-web app. It seems to be related with how RCTNetwork is handled because it isn't mocked out by the react-native-web dependency it defaults to the react-native libraries which rely on native modules.
When i run npx expo start --web -c i'm able to resolve this by updating my metro.config.js
/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config")
const { mergeConfig } = require("@react-native/metro-config")
const path = require("path")

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname)

const {
  resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
} = defaultConfig

const config = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: true,
        inlineRequires: true
      }
    }),
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer/expo")
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: [...assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"), "ttf", "otf"],
    sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"],
    extraNodeModules: {
      "react-native": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-native-web"),
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
      process: require.resolve("process/browser")
    }
  }
}

config.resolver.resolveRequest = (context, moduleName, platform) => {
  if (platform === "web") {
    if (moduleName.endsWith("RCTNetworking")) {
      return {
        filePath: require.resolve("identity-obj-proxy"),
        type: "sourceFile"
      }
    }

    if (moduleName.endsWith("./RCTAlertManager")) {
      return {
        filePath: require.resolve("identity-obj-proxy"),
        type: "sourceFile"
      }
    }
 
  }

  return context.resolveRequest(context, moduleName, platform)
}

module.exports = mergeConfig(defaultConfig, config)


And including global.XMLHttpRequest = global?.originalXMLHttpRequest || global.XMLHttpRequest in my index.js file.
But when i bundle and serve the app npx expo export -p web && npx serve dist --single it doesn't work.
I get various issues.
For example

index-fae72be5f22c92931a109296bd504de0.js:5417 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'node') which comes from the identify-obj-proxy dependency. But if I fix that then i get
TypeError: r(...).default.addListener is not a function which comes from node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js

    if (this.readyState !== this.OPENED) {
      throw new Error('Request has not been opened');
    }
    if (this._sent) {
      throw new Error('Request has already been sent');
    }
    this._sent = true;
    const incrementalEvents =
      this._incrementalEvents || !!this.onreadystatechange || !!this.onprogress;

    this._subscriptions.push(
      RCTNetworking.addListener('didSendNetworkData', args =>
        this.__didUploadProgress(...args),
      ),
    );
    this._subscriptions.push(
      RCTNetworking.addListener('didReceiveNetworkResponse', args =>
        this.__didReceiveResponse(...args),
      ),
    );
    this._subscriptions.push(
      RCTNetworking.addListener('didReceiveNetworkData', args =>
        this.__didReceiveData(...args),
      ),
    );

I feel like I've tried everything. If anyone has any tips for this it would be super appreciated!
